# 'An object reference is required' error on a missing method

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
using System.Drawing;

int offset;
string longest = "";
Font F = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
list.Aggregate("", (max, cur) => max.Length > cur.Length ? longest = max : longest = cur);
offset = Graphics.MeasureString(longest, F).Width;
```

And I get an

> "An object referece is required for the non-static [...]"

error on the `Graphics.MeasureString` method, but using:

```
offset = new Graphics.MeasureString(longest, F).Width;
```

Raises a "The type name `MeasureString` does not exist in the type `Graphics`". The weird thing is, the compiler *does* find the `MeasureString` method in the `Graphics` class (or whatever it is) when the `new` word is abscent.

So my problem is that when the compiler finds the method it is static and when initialising a new instance of it - it cannot be found.

Comment: The Graphics class has no public constructor.  Have a look at this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y289054(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `new Graphics.MeasureString(...)` attempts to create a new instance of the type `MeasureString` found either as a subtype of the `Graphics` type or as a type in the `Graphics` namespace. You need to call `MeasureString` on an `Graphics` *instance*, which you should obtain from somewhere which has a device context.

Comment: If you want this thing to be run inside your different class than class with WindowForms, you simply need to provide an argument in method constructor. If this is WindowsForms class, just use `CreateGraphics().MeasureString(longest, F).Width;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the `Graphics` object. In WinForms (this looks like WinForms code):

```
var graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
...
offset = graphics.MeasureString(longest, F).Width;
```